# ASP.net website only showing plain text

Tags: asp.net

so I made a website in Visual Studio 2015 community, but when I upload it to my website it only shows the source (www.fluffykillers.com) what should i do?
I have my .htacces file to point to Default.aspx

Comment: That looks like ASP.NET is not enabled (or supported) by your hoster. What hoster are you using and are you sure its supporting ASP.NET sites?

Comment: I don't know, I have my website at freewha.com, bcuz I have no money

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed in my comment, the hoster that you are using (freewha.com) is not supporting ASP.NET sites, it only supports PHP as it seems.

So you will have to find another hoster that supports ASP.NET sites.

Comment: Can you recommend some please?

Comment: Well AFAIK the service from [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/pricing-offers/) can be used for free (IIRC they offer pretty much free, I guess that should be enough for a small site).